# Google api not found when loading page with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps, google-visualization

So I've got a working web page that uses the Google maps api, but when I try to load this page using jquery ajax the script no longer works.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
</script>
```

I get the javascript error "google is not defined", yet it seems to me that google is defined in the jsapi file I am including, so I'm confused as to why it can't find it.  Is this a timing issue?  Any ideas?

Comment: When you say you're loading the page with ajax what exactly do you mean? Can you add that code as well? My thoughts are that when you're loading the html into the page with ajax, the scripts are either not there or are not getting downloaded.

Comment: `https://www.google.com/jsapi` isn't done loading before the second executes. One of the reasons why you shouldn't include javascript in pages that you load with ajax.

Comment: You are brilliant sir.  Of course, there's no reason to include javascript in the ajax page.  I'll just include it in the container page.  Problem solved!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to include the javascript in the container page rather than the ajax page.